# How to search & replace using Regex in Notepad++ to change characters in first column only of a csv

Tags: regex, csv

I have a csv file provided by a client with a filepath in the first column, then a blank column, the a file size, then two timestamps, then an owner, and a final column which is usually, though not exclusively, blank. It can contain text of the first 500 characters of the file.

Some of the filepaths contain single occurrences of the double-quote character.

My problem is finding the regex I can use in Notepad++ to find these occurrences in only the first column, and replace them with pairs of double-quotes, so they are properly escaped for a csv file.

Here are three example lines:

```
"/TCH-EXP/mnt/office/dept/ped/Bill New Structure/_Personal Folders/TFR/PowerPoint/Privat/Emilie Føs"da.ppt","",143872,Mon Mar  5 10:02:22 2007,Mon Mar  5 10:02:22 2007,"TFR012",""

"/TCH-EXP/mnt/office/dept/ped/Bill New Structure/_Personal Folders/TFR/Tfr/Siemens Data/Halfdan "B" data (2).msg","",2092544,Mon Feb  9 09:22:32 2004,Mon Feb  9 09:22:32 2004,"TFR012",""

"/TCH-EXP/mnt/office/dept/ped/Bill New Structure/_Personal Folders/TFR/Tfr/Siemens Data/Halfdan "B" data "20-nov-2003".msg","",1060864,Mon Feb  9 09:22:32 2004,Mon Feb  9 09:22:32 2004,"TFR012",""
```

In the first line, I need `Føs"da.ppt` to become `Føs""da.ppt` 
In the second line I just need `"B"` to be `""B""`
In the third line I need `"B"` to be `""B""` and `"20-nov-2003"` to be `""20-nov-2003""`

Is there one regex search & replace I could use to address all three scenarios?

Thanks very much!

I've tried a simple search using capture groups to spot occurrences of " in the first column, but only by counting the appropriate number of commas.

```
Search: ^("/TCH-.*)"(.*","",.*,"")
Replace: $1""$2
```

This seems to work on the first example where there is only one " in the path.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do if you use notepad++ is make use of `\G` and use a negative lookahead to make sure that the `"` you select is not followed by `,"` or the end of the string.

Then replace with the full match `$0` followed by an extra double quote.

**Find what**

```
(?:\G(?!^)|"/TCH-EXP)[^"]+\K"+(?!,"|$)
```

**Replace with**

```
$0"
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|"/TCH-EXP)` End of the previous match but not at the start or match `"/TCH-EXP`
- `[^"]+` Match 1+ times not double quote
- `\K"+` Forget what was matched and match 1+ times `"`
- `(?!,"|$)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not `,"` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPbOiF/1)

Comment: Thanks very much, that certainly works for the examples I've given. I applied it to a file of 8000 rows, it worked on the majority of rows. 
I did subsequently find other examples where it hadn't worked, for example where the first column contained a , before the ", such as:

Comment: @Mishkadad I have updated the regex allowing it to match a comma. https://regex101.com/r/ZPbOiF/1

Comment: Yes, it did. I'm sorry it took me so long to come back and express my appreciation, thank you for your help!